# How do I install asleap tool in Ubuntu?

Tags: kali-linux-tools

This is the link for the tool - https://github.com/joswr1ght/asleap

I cloned it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/joswr1ght/asleap
Cloning into 'asleap'...
remote: Counting objects: 36, done.
remote: Total 36 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 36
Unpacking objects: 100% (36/36), done.*
```

Then used:

```
$ cd asleap
$ ls
asleap.c    COPYING      ieee8021x.h      md4.c       sha1.c   version.h
asleap.h    data         ietfproto.h      md4.h       sha1.h
byteswap.h  genkeys.c    joshlea.dump     radiotap.h  THANKS
common.c    genkeys.val  Makefile         README      utils.c
common.h    ieee80211.h  makefile.cygwin  scripts     utils.h

$ make
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g   -c -o sha1.o sha1.c
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g   -c -o common.o common.c
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g   -c -o utils.o utils.c
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g asleap.c -o asleap common.o utils.o sha1.o -lpcap -lcrypt -lcrypto
asleap.c: In function ‘main’:
asleap.c:1398:6: warning: variable ‘findleaptimeout’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int findleaptimeout = 5;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g md4.c genkeys.c -o genkeys common.o utils.o -lpcap -lcrypt -lcrypto
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g   -c -o asleap.o asleap.c
asleap.c: In function ‘main’:
asleap.c:1398:6: warning: variable ‘findleaptimeout’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int findleaptimeout = 5;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I../../.. -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3 -ggdb -g   -c -o genkeys.o genkeys.c

$ make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, it would be helpful if you posted the output that you get when you try these commands.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error messages you see on running that command!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What exact error messages you got?

Comment: Please use code formatting for commands and command output: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @rviertel I added outputs in the post.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Check the post again, added outputs.

Comment: @N0rbert My Ubuntu version is 18.04.1 LTS. Check the post again I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled this software successfully on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libssl-dev libpcap-dev

cd ~/Downloads
https://github.com/joswr1ght/asleap
cd asleep
make
```

For your information: its `Makefile` does not contain install procedure.

So after compilation you can use executables directly by `./asleap` and `./genkeys`.

Comment: How do I call it from anywhere like other tools?

Thank you  @n0rbert

Comment: You can add their directory path to $PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient way to install libxcrypt, libxcrypt-dev, and asleap.
I hope this will solve the issue as well.

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libssl-dev libpcap-dev libcrypt-dev

sudo apt-get install gdebi

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libx/libxcrypt/libxcrypt1_2.4-4_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi libxcrypt1_2.4-4_amd64.deb

wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/libx/libxcrypt/libxcrypt-dev_2.4-4_arm64.deb
sudo gdebi libxcrypt-dev_2.4-4_arm64.deb

wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u4_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u4_amd64.deb

wget http://http.kali.org/pool/main/a/asleap/asleap_2.2-1kali7_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi asleap_2.2-1kali7_amd64.deb
```

Note: libxcrypt won't install without libxcrypt1 so don's skip the step in ubuntu.