# How do i install asleap on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, git, make

i want to install asleap from https://github.com/joswr1ght/asleap, i already clone using git clone, cd the folder, do command "make" but i got this error

```
gcc -pipe -Wall -D_LINUX -D_OPENSSL_MD4 -g3  asleap.c -o asleap common.o utils.o sha1.o -lpcap -lxcrypt -lcrypto
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcrypt: No such file or directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Makefile:32: asleap] Error 1
```

i already see [How do I install asleap tool in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063301/how-do-i-install-asleap-tool-in-ubuntu) and i tried it, i think 2 of the **wget** links are removed cuz if i open it, it says page not found and in terminal it says

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-08-20 01:15:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

anyone have alternative package or something?

Libxcrypt1 and libxcrypt-dev already installed btw, but i still can't install asleap, saying same error(lxcrypt thing)

Comment: Is libxcrypt1 installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed, the broken link is only libssl and asleap, but i try do the make again, still got libxcrypt error